# intellij breakpoint with grails 3/groovy DUMMY exception thrown

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, groovy

Recently I can't set a breakpoint in Intellij Grails 3 because I get pages of stacktrace starting:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: writable for class: DUMMY
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:52)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:307)
at DUMMY$_closure1.doCall(DUMMY.groovy:1)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaMethod.invoke(ClosureMetaMethod.java:84)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1215)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1125)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1024)
```

and so on and on and on.  I have a single breakpoint, no watch conditions or anything else.  So who is the DUMMY here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20734719/no-such-property-springsecurityservice-for-class-dummy

Comment: Not sure if it has anything to do with it, but I recently upgraded Intellij to 2017.1.2 and grails to 3.2.8.  I said I can't set a breakpoint; what I meant is that I can set one but as soon as I hit it I get reams of stacktrace from something related to DUMMY.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No such property: springSecurityService for class: DUMMY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20734719/no-such-property-springsecurityservice-for-class-dummy)